# special characters laravel routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I was trying to route to a controller. It works fine everytime, but when there is a (&) in the url, it stops working. I searched on the net and found out (:all) can be used. It worked but when the last url segment has (&) i have to put a slash(/) at the end of the url to make it work.

ex. in this 2nd route works correctly and first one does not work

```
Route::get('abc/abc/(:any)', array('uses' => 'abc@abc'));
Route::get('abc/abc/(:all)/do', array('uses' => 'abc@do'));
```

ex. in this none of route works correctly

```
Route::get('abc/abc/(:all)', array('uses' => 'abc@abc'));
Route::get('abc/abc/(:all)/do', array('uses' => 'abc@do'));
```

ex. in this both route works correctly

```
Route::get('abc/abc/(:all)/', array('uses' => 'abc@abc'));
Route::get('abc/abc/(:all)/do', array('uses' => 'abc@do'));
```

I just want to find out a way in which i can provide accepted letters in url segment.

Answer (score 0):

& is a special character within the context of a URL. You shouldn't include it in your paths. Most likely what is happening is the request parser is looking at the & and then determining that this is a malformed query string ie: some/path/?foo=1&bar=2 when malformed might look like some/path/&foo=1&bar=2

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp